# Обновить listview методом notifyDataSetChanged сохранив текущее положение

Tags: java, android, listview, recyclerview

Есть `listview` в котором данные обновляются сверху, как сообщения вконтакте, проблема в том, что когда я получаю следующую часть items `listview` для обновления.

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_messages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@null"
    android:divider="@null" />
```

Пробовал сохранять текущее положение `firstVisibleItem` в методе `onScrollStateChanged()`, но это неправильно работает:

```
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState)
{
    if (enableLoading)
    {
        if (currentVisibleItemCount > 0 && scrollState ==  SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL)
        {
            int i = 0;
            if (currentFirstVisibleItem == 7)
            {
                updateMessagesList();//get 20 elements
            }
            _listView.setSelection(i+20);
        }
    }
}

public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount)
{
    currentFirstVisibleItem = firstVisibleItem;
    currentVisibleItemCount = visibleItemCount;
    currentTotalItemCount = totalItemCount;
}
```

Догрузка должна быть какбы "незаметной" и не влиять на текущее положение.

Итак, я начал скролить, сработало условие `firstVisibleItem == 7`
Если я буду сетать значение в `listview.setSelection(firstVisibleItem)`, а я сейчас продолжаю например скролить `listview`, тогда и метод `listView.setSelection(i+20);` **будет работать, если только я 7 елемент "дергну" и остановлюсь на нем же.** А на самом деле как будет - меня попросту вернет назад(в моему случае на 27 елемент в списке), потому что я продолжаю скролить, а `currentFirstVisibleItem` уже не равен  - 7, а тот на котором я остановлюсь, а ведь я могу и не остановливаться, а просто скролить, что-то например искать; плюс еще возможна задержка 1-2 секунды, потому данные приходят с API.

Данные обновляю методом  `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

Как мне добавлять значения до `listview` как бы на заднем фоне, и чтобы при добавлении не терялся `currentPosition`?

**Решение**

```
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) 
{    
    firstVisibleItem = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
    if(firstVisibleItem == 0){
    if (loading == true) 
    {
        loading = false;
        loadMoreItems();
    }
}
```

Плюс перестроил активити с listview на recyclerview. Даже скорость адпатера увеличилась. То есть заметно при работе с большим количеством.

Comment: Попробуйте переделать всё на современный RecyclerView вместо устаревшего ListView. В первом есть методы типа notifyItemRangeInserted

Comment: вообще должно состояние сохраняться и в listview без проблем

Comment: @andreich, полагаю, что состояние сохраняется, но позиции элементов сдвигаются. Т.е. на экране все тот же 10 элемент, но он уже не тот, что был раньше))))

Comment: @andreich совершенно верно. Я подозреваю, что оно делается как-то по-другому. Возможно как то в ином потоке паралельно, но я не знаю возможно ли так или как-нибудь по-другому

Comment: @IgorLevkivskiy, я написал это в ответ, если это действительно работает - то вы можете отметить ответ "верным", нажав на галочку слева от его тела.

Comment: @IgorLevkivskiy, либо вы можете сами написать ответ и в нём привести код, которым вы это сделали)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте переделать всё на современный `RecyclerView` вместо устаревшего `ListView`. В первом есть методы типа `notifyItemRangeInserted`, которые уведомят адаптер о наличии новых элементов в некотором диапазоне и не вызовут перерисовки всего списка